# How do i reorder these HighCharts plots?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to display a number of distributions using HighCharts in the same image.
[1]: https://imgur.com/a/cwQsyW5

Here is the corresponding JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ayr84f0/

```
     plotOptions: {
                areasplinerange: {
                    marker: '{enabled: false}',
                    states: '{hover: {enabled: false}}' 
                    
                    
                },
                dataSorting: {
                    enabled: true,
                    sortKey: 'zIndex'
                },
```

The problem i'm currently having is that the ordering/ allocation of plots on the y-axis seems predetermined by the HighCharts library, and not based on user input. I don't mean how and where the plots overlap (which is solvable by better utilizing the zIndex), but for example why the "orange" plot always gets allocated to the bottom slot/ y-axis=0, and "chocolate" always on top/ y-axis=8.

I'd like for the plots to follow the legend ordering.(from top to bottom: vanilla, coconut, strawberry, etc.)

I've tried using dataSorting with the zIndex as a key value, yet the ordering never changed. (The ordering of the legend did.) Does anyone see what i might be doing wrong or might have any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order depends on your data. The second and third value in the data array determines the position on the y-axis.

```
data: [
    // x, y-low, y-high
    [0, 0, 5],
    [1, 9, 1],
    [2, 5, 2]
]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9kjr4vws/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.areasplinerange.data

Comment: Thank you, i was so focused on getting HighCharts working that it didn't occur to me to actually inspect the data.